# JPA two entities using the same @JoinTable

Tags: jpa

I have User which has Roles and User has a Group, which also can have Roles. I need an easy way to get all the Roles a User have directly or indirectly.

I'm thinking about something like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User{
@Id
private Integer id;
@OneToMany
@JoinTable(name = "USER_ROLES", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID"), 
inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID")   )
private List<Roles> roles;
@ManyToOne
private List<Group> group;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "GROUP")
public class Group{
@Id
private Integer id;
@OneToMany
@JoinTable(name = "USER_ROLES", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "GROUP_ID"), 
inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID")   )
private List<Roles> roles;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "ROLE")
public class Role{
@Id
private Integer id;
@Column
private String name;
}
```

...but this way I need two steps: first I can get direct Roles, and then the indirect Roles, and I need to merge the two collections. Is there a simpler or more convenient way doing this?

From SQL it would be easy doing this:

```
USER      USER_ROLES  ROLE
----      ----------  ----
ID        USER_ID     ID
GROUP_ID  GROUP_ID    NAME
          ROLE_ID

SELECT *
FROM   USER u
JOIN   USER_ROLES u_r ON (u.ID = u_r.USER_ID)
JOIN   USER_ROLES g_r (u.GROUP_ID = u_r.GROUP_ID);
```

Comment: You mentioned, that from SQL it would be easy, but this is basically a query. You can do the same with JPQL. But you cannot structure table that way, so you cannot structure your entity that way. Imagine table generation from entities now.

Answer (score 0):

This is generally a bad idea.

- If a `User` has the same id as a `Group` there will be a conflict.
- You cannot make use of foreign key constraints in your db.
- Other strange things will eventually happen.
- Implementation of this in JPA is hard and very error prone.

Use separate tables between `Role` and `Group`, `Role` and `User` and `Group` and `User`.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear: User and Group don't use the same ID - they both have theirs. In the join table (USER_ROLES) there are separate USER_ID and GROUP_ID along with ROLE_ID. And in the mapping they have different @JoinColumns. Sorry, this setup is meant to be optimized for simplified SQL usage. But I'm open to any solution for the core problem: I have two entities (User and Group) referencing to the same third entity (Role); Group has many Users; and in most of the time I need to query all the direct and indirect Roles of a User. I need an optimized setup for this in JPA or Hibernate.

Comment: If you have a join table with 3 columns (`role_id`, `user_id` and `group_id`) you cannot enforce unique constraints because either `user_id` or `group_id` will be NULL. This is error prone and isn't a normalized database desin. Go with separate join tables.